# How plausible is this religion?

Tags: society, religion

the Cavnians organized their civilization around the geometric structure of Bismuth crystals, this is because it is believed that Bismuth crystals contain the energy of the Provider.
When Ayak, the largest of Zavnious’s moons, is at the lowest point on its elliptical orbit the sacred crystal glow a myriad of colours (Cavnian scientists have not yet discovered why) this was believed to be the thoughts and feelings of the Provider.
Cavnian architecture, writing and fashion are all very geometric and cubic and Bismuth is very common in the jewelry of both sexes.
As the Provider is also the deity of the soil and sky, Cavnians take their environmental impact very seriously.

Comment: Please give a good read at our [help]. We avoid questions which will be answered with opinions, and this is one of them

Comment: It would be much better if you tried to address the issues pointed out in comments instead of rushing to accept an answer in just 20 minutes.

Comment: I updated my answer after you updated the question. But it would be nice if you would refrain from editing your questions in ways which invalidate existing answers. The people who answered your questions do not receive a notification when the question gets changed, and it makes them look bad when their answers now no longer appear to address the question.

Comment: I apologize and will keep this in mind for farther edits.

Answer (score 3):

***Note:** This answer is based on a previous version of this question which did not mention any specifics about the culture and religion in this scenario except that they worship a bismuth crystal*

---

In order for a religion to be plausible, it needs a bit more substance. You need some mythology which can be told and some moral principles which can be derived from them. Every civilization needs a basic groundwork of universally accepted rules and moral principles in order to function. The reason why Christianity was the glue which held European medieval society together was because the bible is a source for such rules and moral principles. It provided guidelines for what is and is not socially accepted behavior, and legitimized to impose corrective measures on those who break them. (The bible says "thou shalt not commit adultery". So if one of us commits adultery, then we are not just allowed to punish them, it's our sacred duty. End of discussion.)

Doing all of that "just" around a Bismuth crystal is a bit far-fetched. Yes, Bismuth is pretty, but it doesn't *do* anything or *say* anything.

You certainly can have a religion in which Bismuth is sacred, but you need to do a lot more worldbuilding around it in order to make it plausible. *Why* do people in your world worship bismuth? Does it have any (imagined or real) supernatural properties? How do those properties work (or are believed to work) and how do they affect peoples everyday lives? Is it somehow connected to any (imagined or real) deities? What is that connection, who are those deities and why are they important to the mortals?

These are questions for you as a worldbuilder to answer.

---

***Edit after the question was updated:***

It appears that what you have here is a pretty usual monotheistic religion. There are a lot of those in the real world, so there is nothing implausible about it. The details do of course need some flashing out. Like how did the religion start? How did it spread? How is it organized? What exactly are its tenets? Are there any schisms in this religion? But I assume that you have those somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Of course. You see, theere was this religious activist, gaining some followers, only to be executed by the existing autonomous religious authorities by forcing a Bismuth crystal down his throat  (a usual eay of execution at the time and place). Since his death (and presumed resurrection a few days later), his followers gained traction and bingo, a few centuries or a millennium later their religion became dominant in the part of the world that eventually reached the industrial revolution.

Granted, venerating the tool of the execution is morbid and bizzare (and somey people even hang the crystals on the wall of their homes, or wear pendants with a crystal on their neck!) , but perhaps the readers will forgive us this one implausible and extravagant details, it is a fantasy (of a sci-fi?), after all....

Comment: I apologize for undermining your answer, it is plausible and exotic but I found that it did not fit with my preconception of Cavnian culture which in my mind is void of hostility and religions upheaval.

Comment: @PrinceThomasthe42nd then we can imagine their religion will be full of nonsensical chlichés, like "if anyone hits your arm, offer the other one" or "Do unto others as they would like you to do unto them", and it will be a religion of peace and tranquility, promising eternal reward for the suffering (because what else can a religion offer...). After centuries of low profile, low impact, we can imagine a totally implausible (but this is fantasy, remember) step of the Emperor himself converting, and declaring the religion to be the state one.

Comment: @PrinceThomasthe42nd and if that happens, then we can imagine the Empire, suddenly preaching the doctrine of peace, lack of hostility and upheaval will succumb to those more violent barbarians, and a sort of Dark Ages will follow, the knowledge being carried on by the competing religion of Antimony Crystal (but also by religious structures of the Bismuth, since these will be pretty much the only literate remnants), until a new, reborn Bismuth culture appears, based on wild commerce, discovery, proselytizing, eventually starting scientific revolution. Well...sorry, this is totally implausible.